# Dates for every month to show

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have distinct category code that I need to join with every month form a start date to an end data.

```
DECLARE @Start DATE, @End DATE
SET @Start = '20170101'
SET @End = getdate()

SELECT        Category_Cd, CalMonth = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) < @End)
FROM            dbo.Category
WHERE        (Category_Cd LIKE N'0%')
```

because there is no join i get this:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I do not want a join, I just want every category code to have every data from the start to the end show. Thanks for your help.

```
DECLARE @Start DATE, @End DATE
SET @Start = '20170101'
SET @End = getdate()

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) < @End
```

this code does return every start to end date like I want. Now I just need it to be done with each category code.

```
01001 2017-02-01
01001 2017-03-01
01001 2017-04-01
01001 2017-05-01
01002 2017-02-01
01002 2017-03-01
01002 2017-04-01
01002 2017-05-01
01003 2017-02-01
01003 2017-03-01
01003 2017-04-01
01003 2017-05-01
```

Comment: ***I do not want a join*** ... Well then you need a `JOIN` Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: SQL can only return data that exists in the database, or is constructed as part of the query.  So if you don't have the desired date stored in the system, SQL can't retrieve it.  So you're choice is to construct the missing data somehow so it can be returned, usually via a JOIN...  I want all dates in range A cross joined to all the category codes so that every category has all the dates in range A...

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/GECI89631)**

```
DECLARE @Start DATE, @End DATE;
SET @Start = '20170101';
SET @End = getdate();

WITH myMonths as (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) [Date]
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
    AND DATEADD(MONTH,number+1,@Start) < @End
)
SELECT *
FROM category
CROSS JOIN myMonths
```